# How can I select all test names in one row if there is multiple names and not in multiple rows SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, where-clause

I have the following SQL Server `select` statement :

```
SELECT 
    a.patient_no AS 'File No', 
    b.order_id AS 'Order Id',  
    e.testname AS 'Test'
FROM 
    patients a, lab_orders b, customers c, order_details d, labtests e  
WHERE 
    a.patient_no = b.patient_no 
    AND b.custid = c.custid
    AND b.order_id = d.order_id 
    AND d.testid = e.testid
    AND c.CustId > 1
    AND CAST(b.order_date AS TIME) BETWEEN '01:00:00' AND '23:50:50'
    AND CAST(b.order_date AS DATE) BETWEEN '01/10/2020' AND '03/10/2020'
```

The output is like this :

```
File No Order Id    Test
-----------------------------------
33926   2000001001  SEMEN ANALYSIS
33900   2000001002  AMMONIA
33966   2000001044  TSH
33966   2000001044  PROLACTIN
33967   2000001045  HGB 
33967   2000001045  Pregnancy Test in Blood (SERUM)
33967   2000001045  H. PYLORI (Serum Ab) 
34000   2000001079  BACTERIAL CULTURE AND ANTIBIOTIC SENSITIVITY
34001   2000001080  BACTERIAL CULTURE AND ANTIBIOTIC SENSITIVITY
34002   2000001081  BACTERIAL CULTURE AND ANTIBIOTIC SENSITIVITY
34003   2000001082  BACTERIAL CULTURE AND ANTIBIOTIC SENSITIVITY
34020   2000001100  FSH
34020   2000001100  LH
34020   2000001100  TSH
34020   2000001100  PROLACTIN
```

But I need the output to be in one row for each order id and test names appear in one row not multiple rows like this example order id 2000001100   the output I need it like this :

```
34020   2000001100   FSH , LH , TSH , PROLACTIN
```

How can I do that in SELECT statement ?

Comment: What is your version of SQL Server?

Comment: @forpas microsoft SQL SERVER 2014

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: @marc_s thank you marc useful and helpful tips , I used it . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want string aggregation. If you are running SQL Server 2017 or higher, you can use `string_agg()`:

```
select p.patient_no as file_no, lo.order_id, string_agg(lt.testname, ', ') as testnames
from patients p
inner join lab_orders lo on  p.patient_no = lo.patient_no 
inner join customers c on lo.custid = c.custid
inner join order_details od on lo.order_id = od.order_id 
inner join labtests lt on od.testid = lt.testid
where
    c.CustId > 1
    and cast(lo.order_date as time) between '01:00:00' and '23:50:50'
    and cast(lo.order_date as date) between '20201001' and '20201003'
group by p.patient_no, lo.order_id
```

Important notes:

- *always* use explicit, standard joins rather than old-school (with the `on` keyword), implicit joins (with commas in the from clause): this syntax from decades should not be used in new code
- *meaningful* table aliases make the query easier to write and read
- do not use single quotes for column aliases or other identifiers; they are meant for literal strings only
- `YYYYMMDD` is the most portable date format in SQL Server, that works regardless of regional settings

Comment: thank you , I tried it and got the following error                                                                                           'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name.                              I will try to upgrade my version and check it :)